# PHP date() - if between Sunday 5pm and Friday 5pm

Tags: php

I wrote a php script that gets called every minute by a cron job - this script contains a function that is only supposed to execute if the current date and time is between Sunday 5pm and Friday 5pm:

```
if( ... date and time is between Sunday 5pm and Friday 5pm ... ) {

// do something 

} else {

// do nothing 

}
```

Any ideas how this `if` statement could look like in php?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @Uchiha: sorry if I was not clear about that. I am not sure about how to achieve that "if" statement in php

Comment: No, it is always between Sunday and Sunday. What about Saturday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$dayOfWeek = date('w');
$hourOfDay = date('H');
if(
($dayOfWeek > 0 && $dayOfWeek < 5) // not Sunday, Friday and Saturday
|| ($dayOfWeek == 0 && $hourOfDay > 17) // Sunday and after 5pm
|| ($dayOfWeek == 5 && $hourOfDay < 17) // Friday and before 5pm
 ){
//in range
}else{
//out range
}
```

Comment: Just a tip for answering questions, remember, your answer should not just be a referrence for the user asking the question. This is a wiki site and your answer should be a reference for everyone visiting this page. Describe in short what your code does, how it works and most importantly, where should it be used, etc...

Comment: magegaga condition is wrong, how can it work with date('H') > 17 && date('H) < 17. It always return false

Comment: @ Ferrrmolina Thanks for your tip. I just try to answer the question asap first. and will complete it after feedback :D. Will note that!

Comment: yeah @Leonardo you are right i will not edit the code for you :) voted for you

Answer (score 4):

If you want the if condition, then it could be like this

```
if((date("w") >= 0 && date('H') > 17) && (date( "w") <=4) && date('H') < 17)) {
 // run your code
}
```

check php manual for options "w" (denotes week day) and "H" (denotes hour)

at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php